# Strange received data

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

I try send some data to my Google script (I just learn how it works) but I understand what I get.

First cdoe.
Spimple (for testing) page on my local computer.

test6.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pl'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div onclick ="A1()"> TEST </div>
  </body>
   <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript">
  
  $.ajaxSetup({
   url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/****/exec",
   type: "post",
   
   
 });
 function A1() {
  
  var d1 = { test1 : "pass1" };
        var d2 = JSON.stringify(d1);
    
    
     var res = $.ajax ({   
   data: d1
  });
  
  res.done(function (odpserv, textStatus, jqXHR) {   
     console.log(odpserv);
     console.log(textStatus);
     console.log(jqXHR);
    });   
 }
 
  </script>
```

code.gs

```js
function doPost(e){
  
 var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('****');
 var sh = SS.getSheetByName('A');
                
 sh.appendRow([e]);
       
 return ContentService.createTextOutput("OK").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  
}
```

1.
 If I send by jQuery  data - d1 - I expect to recive:

```
{ test1 : "pass1" }
```

but I recive

`{parameter={test1=pass1}, contextPath=, contentLength=11, queryString=, parameters={test1=[Ljava.lang.Object;@45c41746}, postData=FileUpload}`

If I send d2 i recive

`{parameter={{"test1":"pass1"}=}, contextPath=, contentLength=17, queryString=, parameters={{"test1":"pass1"}=[Ljava.lang.Object;@7ec35331}, postData=FileUpload}`

Can somebody explain that?
Why I recive some additional parmetrs?

2. If  I send d1
    `var d1 = { test1 : "pass1" };` 
   so in code.gs I can take data by:

`var r1 = e.parameter.test1 // pass1`

bu when I send 
 `var d2 = JSON.stringify(d1);`

`var r1 = e.parameter.test1 // undefined`

How I should take recived data?

Comment: It should not be surprising that if you stringify the input before sending it, that it is not seen as an object. Thus when sending `d2` you must first de stringify: `var d1 = JSON.parse(e.parameter); var r1 = d1.test1;`

Comment: Still something wrong.
    <code>
var d1 = { test1 : "pass1" };
var d2 = JSON.stringify(d1);
</code>

If I send "d2",  
<code> var d1 = JSON.parse(e.parameter); </code>
 throws me error
<code> Unexpected token: o, SyntaxError</code>

Answer (score 0):

*If you don't know what look for, you never find it*

Answer/ issue:

Post data Google hide in `parameters`

To read it use: 
 `e.postData.contents`

[INFO](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)